# Maltparser vs Freeling for Spanish dependency parser

Tags: nlp, parsing, dependency-grammar

I need to parse a Spanish corpus with syntactic dependencies. I have tried both Freeling and Maltparser, they both give similar results, but with some divergence. I need the highest accuracy possible, mainly in the dependencies between the verb and its dependents. Which one should I use?

Comment: deppattern is also an option, I guess.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request to suggest a tool, which attracts opinionated answers. OP may want to ask it on [Software Recommendations.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), provided that the requirements are specified with more details.

Comment: I think this is on-topic because the question concerns a tool that is used for research in linguistics. Questions on research methods should be on-topic. A suitable answer may also involve linguistically relevant aspects such as how the different performance of the parsers should be evaluated, and whether a 'best' parse exists.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use more than one tool.

When you have three different tools you can use majority voting to determine your tags. In case of ties, a human arbiter can fix the tags.

Also note that the tools can be trained. When you can afford to create some tailored training data from your corpus you can improve the accuracy of the tagging significantly.